# fastest way to iterate over all pixels of an image in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

i have already read an image as an array :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
face1=misc.imread('face1.jpg')
```

face1 dimensions are `(288, 352, 3)`

i need to iterate over every single pixel and populate a `y` column in a training set i took the following approach  :

```
Y_training = np.zeros([1,1],dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(0, face1.shape[0]): # We go over rows number 
    for j in range(0, face1.shape[1]): # we go over columns number
        if np.array_equiv(face1[i,j],[255,255,255]):
           Y_training=np.vstack(([0], Y_training))#0 if blank
        else:
           Y_training=np.vstack(([1], Y_training))

b = len(Y_training)-1
Y_training = Y_training[:b]
np.shape(Y_training)`
```

`Wall time: 2.57 s`

As i need to do above process for about 2000 images is there any faster approach where we could decrease running time to milliseconds or naonseconds

Comment: For future similar problems you might want to try numba ```@njit``` decorator. So that you get a JIT comiled function that runs very fast

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to perform broadcasted comparison against the white pixel : `[255, 255, 255]` and `ALL` reduce each row with `.all(axis=-1)` and finally convert to `int` dtype. This would give us the output you would have right after exiting the loop.

Thus, one implementation would be -

```
(~((face1 == [255,255,255]).all(-1).ravel())).astype(int)
```

Alternatively, a bit more compact version -

```
1-(face1 == [255,255,255]).all(-1).ravel()
```

Comment: i think it should be  `(~((face1 != [255,255,255]).all(-1).ravel())).astype(int)`, as i need to label white pixels by `0`

Comment: @sanaz Nope. Please check again.

Comment: `(~((face1 == [255,255,255]).all(-1).ravel())).astype(int)` returns `array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])` which labels white pixels with `1` , my own for loop approach labels them with `0`

Comment: @sanaz Try a small sample at your end : `face1 = np.random.randint(0,255,(4,5,3))`. Then set two pixels to white : `face1[2,3] = [255,255,255]; face1[1,2] = [255,255,255]`. Now, set a third pixel to blue : `face1[1,3] = [255,0,0]`. So, now use all the methods you have and see which methods give you array with exactly two 0s. Those are the correct ones.

Comment: what would be the most efficient way to have the result as a column vector not a row vector? having `(101376,1)` instead of  `(101376,)`

Comment: @sanaz NumPy doesn't have the concept of row/column vector. But guessing from the format you have in the question, I would say row vector would be best, whereas making column vector from it won't be too costly either.

Comment: what i meant was having (101376,1) instead of (101376,)

Comment: @sanaz Yeah, that's what I guessed and my comments were based on that assumption.